# Encoding issue with CSV write in Python

Tags: python, excel, postgresql, csv, encoding

I was trying to extract a big amount of data from a PostgreSQL database and then write it to a CSV, but I got a MemoryError. For doing that, I've used the Python StringIO module, and if I'd put a limited number of rows generated by the query it worked just fine; the file was written and there was no problem in importing it as text file on Excel.

Since it gives me back that error, I've tried to write the file row by row like this, with a little function that takes care of the decoding/encoding stuff:

```
def convert_and_write(out_stream, input_value):
    output_value = input_value.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-16','ignore')
    out_stream.write(output_value)

with open( filename, "w" ) as out_file:
    for row in rs:
        tmpstr = ""
        for c in range( len( row ) ):
            xx = str( row[c] ).replace("\"", "").replace( chr(9), " " )
            tmpstr += xx + chr(9)
        convert_and_write( out_file,
            tmpstr.replace( "\n", "-" ).replace( "\r", " " )
        )
        convert_and_write( out_file, "\r\n" )
```

Now the file is written, but when I try to import it as a text on Excel, there's a problem: the lines that divide the columns are over the text, like this

[image]

(I've hidden some data, but you get the idea)

and when I compare the file before/after on Notepad++, the codification seems to be the same (UCS-2 Little Endian), but I can notice strange marks on the first letter of the words of the newest file

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Personally I don't see tabulations as good dividers for CSV. Judging from your sample data, you might want to try using other symbols such as `:`

Comment: Could be something, but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Think you can provide a line of sample data? Need not to be your actual data, just something that reflects how your actual data looks like